# Why my event is NULL even when I subscribe from another form c#

Tags: c#, events, delegates

I'm new in the c# programming, and I have problem with my event that I have created.

I have class named Serial in witch I have made an event:

```
public delegate void dOnPreAmpFrequencyUpdate(object sender, double frequency);
public event dOnPreAmpFrequencyUpdate OnPreAmpFrequencyUpdate;
```

and I want to raise the event from the serial method like this :

```
if (OnPreAmpFrequencyUpdate!=null)
{
    this.OnPreAmpFrequencyUpdate(this, iWorkingParameters.Frequency);
}
```

In my main form I have subscribe the event :

```
public static Serial _serial;
public frmMain()
{
   _serial = new Serial();
   _serial.OnPreAmpFrequencyUpdate += new Serial.dOnPreAmpFrequencyUpdate(_serial_OnPreAmpFrequencyUpdate);

   InitializeComponent();

}

void _serial_OnPreAmpFrequencyUpdate(object sender, double frequency)
{ 
   if (this.IsDisposed) return;
   updatePreAmpFrequency(frequency, null);
}

private void updatePreAmpFrequency(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //update the pre-amp frequency, according to the value
   try
   {
      if (this.InvokeRequired)
      {
         EventHandler ev = new EventHandler(updatePreAmpFrequency);
         this.Invoke(ev, sender, null);
         return;
      }

      double frequency = (double)sender;
      numFrequency.Value = (decimal)frequency;
      numFrequency.ForeColor = Color.Black;
   }
   catch (Exception)
   { }
}
```

I can't understand why when I try to raise my event in my Serial class it is always null even when I subscribe it into my main form.

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: Where is that second code snippet located?  You say that it's in "the serial method" but what method is that and where are you calling it?

Comment: Are you certain that the `Serial` instance you subscribe to is the same as the `Serial` instance that's generating the events? Did you put a breakpoint in the code that generates the events, and make sure that the event invocation list really is null?

Comment: The second code snipped is located in mainForm class that have the same namespace with my serial class. In my serial class I have method that raise up my event (there I get my null exception).My Instance located in my mainForm class (named _serial) and when I put breakpoint I can see that I subscribe the event from my mainForm to my Serial class but still I don't know what I'm missing here..

Comment: I'm new in C# programming, could this be because the event raise up from another from into class? Anyone knows?